# How to deploy Aurelia to GitHub Pages (gh-pages)

Tags: github, github-pages, aurelia

I haven't seen demos of [Aurelia](http://aurelia.io) running in GitHub pages. I wonder if there's a gist or a repo somewhere that shows how it can be done.

Is it just a matter of configuring `gulp` or is there another solution?

Comment: Include all packages into VC and set up your project like this github user did - http://jdanyow.github.io/aurelia-converters-sample/

Comment: i'm going to write a blog post on this later today

Comment: visit https://gitter.im/Aurelia/Discuss for further help

Answer (score 10):

Here is the solution using the [Aurelia navigation skeleton](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation) project as an example when created into your organization as a repository as `aurelia-skeleton-navigation`.

> **Important Note:** This is NOT a production solution.  This is for showing how to run Aurelia within GitHub pages using an Aurelia repository that uses `Gulp`. It is recommended to read about `jspm bundling` an Aurelia app for deployment.

Start a `git` command line after you unzip the current release of the `skeleton-navigation` into `aurelia-skeleton-navigation` directory.

Locally from a `git` and `npm` command line:

`cd <path>/aurelia-skeleton-navigation`

`git init`

`git remote add origin git@github.com:yourorg/aurelia-skeleton-navigation.git`

`git fetch --all`

`git add *`

`git commit -m 'initial commit'`

`git push origin master`

`git branch gh-pages`

`git checkout gh-pages`

edit `.gitignore` and comment out the `jspm_packages` and `dist` paths

```
node_modules
# jspm_packages
bower_components
.idea
.DS_STORE
# /dist
```

`jspm install`

`npm install`

`gulp build`

`git add *`

`git commit -m 'adding resources'`

`git push origin gh-pages`

Navigate to your repository GitHub page:
`http://yourorg.github.io/aurelia-skeleton-navigation`

#### Updating the app on GitHub Pages

Once you make changes to your app in the `master` branch, you can merge those changes into your `gh-pages` and publish:

- `git checkout gh-pages`
- `git merge master`
- `gulp build`
- `git add *`
- `git commit -m 'updates'`
- `git push origin gh-pages`

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to get the bundling working now.

Comment: Thanks @talves! If I may suggest maybe it's worth using gulp-gh-pages, and even maybe creating an example repo?

Comment: Yes. **Once there is a working bundle solution** for Aurelia, setting up a production command for Aurelia (i.e. `gulp deploy`) using `gulp-gh-pages` is a great idea.  I will make a pull request into the skeleton also or create an example repo and update the answer here.

Comment: I've created a blog post based on this post here: http://www.foursails.co/blog/deploy-to-gh-pages/

Comment: I like using SourceTree on windows also along with TortoiseGit. +1 for the mention on the blog post. :)

Comment: @talves - as there is a working solution for bundling Aurelia now (http://blog.durandal.io/2015/06/23/bundling-an-aurelia-application/) - would care to ```create an example repo and update the answer here``` as mentioined in April?

Comment: @nikivancic bundling turned out to not be the only issue, but yes it would be worth a deploy example repo. Let me see what I can throw together once I have some time.