# How to deploy Aurelia to GitHub pages

Tags: javascript, github-pages, aurelia

Is aurelia.io completely client side or does it require server component.

i.e. can it a github page.
thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29831885/how-to-deploy-aurelia-to-github-pages-gh-pages

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29831885/how-to-deploy-aurelia-to-github-pages-gh-pages/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's client-side, nothing in it is server-based:

```
<script src="jspm_packages/github/webreflection/es6-collections@master/es6-collections.js"></script>
<script src="jspm_packages/github/polymer/mutationobservers@0.4.2/MutationObserver.js"></script>
<script src="jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
<script src="config.js"></script>
<script>
  System.import('aurelia-bootstrapper');
</script>
```

Comment: many thanks. So can I use it on a github page.  Suppose I should try.

Comment: Note that it could offer some serve side service if it comes to support pre-rendering in the future, it was one of the possibility mentionned during one of the presentations of his creator.

Comment: This does not answer the question of how to deploy it to `gh-pages`.

Answer (score 2):

As cDima said, it is client side. I've written up a detailed tutorial on deploying Aurelia to GitHub pages here: http://www.foursails.co/blog/deploy-to-gh-pages/

Comment: That link is dead. Amy chance of updating it?